# Как правильно принимать файлы в Angular c ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, angular2, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

У меня есть файл на сервере, который я хочу отправить клиенту.
Я отправлю его так

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditRu([FromBody]IOptionsDiplom options, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!FilesController.Files.Keys.Contains(key))
                    throw new Exception("Файл не существует на сервере");

                options.Bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(UploadFolder, key + ".docx"));
                byte[] bytes;
                using (TaskModel task = new TaskModel(options, FilesFolder))
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => task.EditRu());
                    bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(task.PathFile);
                }
                FilesController.DeleteFile(key);
                return File(bytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", key);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, e);
            }
        }
```

Я также пробовал и так

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditRu([FromBody]IOptionsDiplom options, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!FilesController.Files.Keys.Contains(key))
                    throw new Exception("Файл не существует на сервере");
                string pathUploadFile= Path.Combine(UploadFolder, key + ".docx");
                options.Bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathUploadFile);
                using (TaskModel task = new TaskModel(options, FilesFolder))
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => task.EditRu());
                    await Task.Run(() => System.IO.File.Copy(task.PathFile, pathUploadFile, true));
                }
                return PhysicalFile(pathUploadFile, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, e);
            }
        }
```

И по другому пробовал. У клиента я принимаю файл так

```
this.http.post("Diplom/EditRu", this.body, {
            headers: this.headers(),
            params: params
        }).subscribe(
            result => {
                var contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
                var blob = new Blob([result.arrayBuffer()], { type: contentType });
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(downloadUrl, "_blank");
            },
            error => {
                alert("Не удалось отредактировать файл");
                console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
```

Файл, который принимает клиент поврежден и не отправляется. Файл, который на сервере в порядке и прекрасно открывается. Я специально не удалял файл на сервере и открывал его, и останавливал отладку перед отправкой и открывал его, и оба раза на сервере он открывался просто отлично, но клиенту приходит уже поврежденный файл. Не могу понять я не правильно отправляю файл или принимаю его. То есть до этого

```
return File(bytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", key);
```

Или этого момента

```
return PhysicalFile(pathUploadFile, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

Все отлично, но у клиента уже файл не открывается. Работаю с Angular с ASP.NET.Core Web API

### Я также попробовал следующее

На стороне сервера отправить файл

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(FilesFolder, "test.docx"));
            return File(bytes, _contentTypeWord);
        }
```

А на стороне клиента его принять так

```
    private _downloadFile(data: ArrayBuffer, fileName: string, contentType: string) {
        // Загрузить скаченный файл
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", url);
        link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        link.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
    public test() {
        this.http.post("Diplom/Test", { }, {
            headers: this.headers(),
        }).subscribe(
            result => {
                this._downloadFile(result.arrayBuffer(), "test.docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
            },
            error => {
                alert("Не удалось отредактировать файл");
                console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
            })
    }
```

Получаемый файл все равно не открывается, да и еще весит в 2 раза больше (на сервере 487 КБ, а у клиента 925 КБ). ContentType пробовал такой application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document и такой application/msword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю почему не работает указанный в вопросе вариант. Но решение я нашел, так сказать "в другом лесу"
Я не очень разбираюсь, поэтому просто опишу процесс решения проблемы.
Для начало сразу скажу, что проблема была на стороне клиента. Метод на сервере работал изначально правильно. Я решил использовать другой метод для скачивания файлов "fetch". И наткнулся на следующий пост в [форуме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168090/fetch-api-to-force-download-file).
От туда я взял следующий ответ

```
this.httpClient
    .fetch(url, {method, body, headers})
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
    .then(url => {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });
```

Он у меня тоже не сработал. Я изменил его так

```
fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: this.headers()
        })
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
        .then(url => {
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        });
```

Из-за этой строчки ничего не происходило

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Этот вариант работал, но с изьяном. Он сохранял файл со странным именем и без расширения. Тогда я изменил его так

```
    fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: this.headers()
        })
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
            .then(url => {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.setAttribute("href", url);
                link.setAttribute("download", "test.docx");
                link.style.display = "none";
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            });
```

И это работает!